# What does this C++03 std::allocator function do?

Tags: c++

I was going over a cpp con video, and I couldn't understand how it worked. I understand what it is doing, but now how. I haven't seen these syntaxes before.

```
template<class T> inline void
allocator<T>::construct(pointer p, T const& val)
{
    ::new((void*) p) T(val);
}
```

The allocator decouples memory allocation and object creation, (unlike the new operator). So this is the construction part. So to construct an object a reference to an already constructed `T` object is necessary. That seems circular. 
What is the `::new((void*) p) T(val);` line doing ? 
Also what is `inline void` doing ?

Where can I learn more about things like this in C++ ?

Comment: [Placement new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) constructs an object on memory which is already allocated somehow.

Comment: @VictorGubin There is a name for this ? Thank you.